# How can I get inferred type data with flowtype command?

Tags: flowtype

[flow(1)](https://flowtype.org/docs/cli.html) provides a lots of subcommands, including `flow suggest`, which generates a patch to add type annotations to the given script, and `flow ast`, which generates AST of the given script.

The AST, generated by `flow ast`, does not have the inferred types though, whereas `flow suggest` has very the inferred types.

How can I get the inferred type information that flow(1) creates with flow analysis.

If I have the inferred type information, I could create flow2dst command, a tool to get typescript .d.ts from flowtype script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `flow dump-types`. we're hoping to eventually merge it into `flow ast` so you can get a typed AST from one command.

Comment: The output of `flow dump-types` seems just debug logs, but if `flow ast`  includes the inferred types, it seems great. Thanks to the information.